# SharePoint Navigation Custom Link Security Trimming

Tags: sharepoint

We've got our navigation setup so that subsites show in the global navigation but we have a requirement to also put custom links to external sites which is straight forward.  The tricky part is that some of the custom links need security trimming which you don't get when you add your own links to the navigation.

Just wondering if anyone has got some ideas on how to work around this?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is audience settings - just add a user or group to the textbox on the edit link dialog in navigation settings and only that user/group should see the link.

Comment: Cool that done the trick!  I saw audience settings but didn't think it would act like a security feature.
Paul-Your solution would have worked as well but this is good.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You're right that is a bit tricky!

Is the security on your external sites fixed (and well known), or does it change constantly?

The reason I ask is that you could create a page in your SharePoint site that has the same name as the external site. If the security was well known to you, you could then apply the same permissions to the SharePoint page as is required to access the site.

Your page could then be set up to redirect the user to the external site. That way you have a SharePoint security trimmed item on the navigation based on the page, not on a manually added external link.

However, if the external site's security changes all the time, you would have to keep updating the security on your SharePoint page to keep the two in sync.

Hope that makes sense!